# Display data from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I tried someone tutorial about retrieve data from firebase storage. There's no error when I run on my device, but the progress bar keep load and the data won't appear. This is the activity code and the gradle. Beside that, I have layout activity_friends, item_list.xml, and model named FriendsResponse.

FriendsActivity.java

```
public class FriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @BindView(R.id.friend_list)
    RecyclerView friendList;

    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        init();
        getFriendList();

    }

    private void init(){
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        friendList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    private void getFriendList(){
        Query query = db.collection("Data");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FriendsResponse> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendsResponse>()
                .setQuery(query, FriendsResponse.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FriendsResponse, FriendsHolder>(response) {
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(FriendsHolder holder, int position, FriendsResponse model) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.textName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.textTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
                holder.textCompany.setText(model.getCompany());
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        .into(holder.imageView);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v-> {
                    Snackbar.make(friendList, model.getName()+", "+model.getTitle()+" at "+model.getCompany(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                });
            }

            @Override
            public FriendsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item, group, false);

                return new FriendsHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        };

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        friendList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class FriendsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.name)
        TextView textName;
        @BindView(R.id.image)
        ImageView imageView;
        @BindView(R.id.title)
        TextView textTitle;
        @BindView(R.id.company)
        TextView textCompany;

        public FriendsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.project"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

This is my database structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your code, the database structure is for firebase realtime database, while your code is for firestore.
Instead of using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`, you need to use [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md). Also check the guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start